# What is the Ubuntu equivalent of OSX `chmod -h` flag?

Tags: permissions, ssh, chmod, symbolic-link

In OSX I can set the permissions of the symlink itself (instead of the thing it points to using the -h). From the man page:

```
 -h      If the file is a symbolic link, change the mode of the link itself rather than the file that the link points to.
```

In Ubuntu 14.04 I try to set permissions of a symlink, but it's only set on the symlink target.

It's regarding a symlink from `/home/nagios/.ssh/someprivatekey` to `/somewhere/else/privatekey`, so permissions are important for ssh. How can I achieve this?

Comment: So, why do you need this symlink?

Comment: are you sure ssh cares about the permissions on the symbolic link and not the permissions on /somewhere/else/privatekey?

Comment: @Random832 Yes, I may have drawn the wrong conclusion, I was also a bit confused about how the permissions were displayed in the `ls -l` output (`lrwxrwxrwx`).

Comment: @muru I was creating a (buildserver) Docker image which uses an ssh key to access all kinds of servers. I don't want to put the private key inside because of different reasons (i.e. if I want to host it on docker hub). So I symlinked it and have it point to a volume that's only mounted once the image is ran. Although, come to think of it, I could have also changed the key location using `.ssh/config` :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not possible. There is no way since permissions on a symlink are meaningless (a symlink is not a file; it only points to a file).  The way to do this with Linux is through [ACL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs) though.

[symlink](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/symlink.html) are explained as...

> The values of the file mode bits for the created symbolic link are unspecified. All interfaces specified by POSIX.1-2008 shall behave as if the contents of symbolic links can always be read, except that the value of the file mode bits returned in the st_mode field of the stat structure is unspecified.

---

The difference is here: [chmod](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=chmod) and [chmod](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod)... it is BSD versus Linux.

---

Not sure if it is important but regarding SSH: it uses  [stat(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat), not lstat(2) to get the permissions.

- stat() stats the file pointed to by path and fills in buf.
- lstat() is identical to stat(), except that if path is a symbolic link, then the link itself is stat-ed, not the file that it refers to.

Comment: The ability to set permissions on symlinks is not specified in even the latest version, it's a BSD extension.

Comment: @Random832 hmm that might be more acurate yes. I read that bit today on SO but did not do a check on this :D

Comment: Incidentally POSIX does specify the `fchmodat` function, which can be used to change the mode of symbolic links (optional feature - systems that do not support it, including Linux, return error EOPNOTSUPP), but nothing in the `chmod` command to use this. Only `-R` is defined in POSIX.

Comment: symlink permissions _are meaningless **on Linux**_. On systems where you can change them (with `lchmod(2)` or `fchmodat(2)`...), they do have a meaning (allow/deny `readlink()` (read) or path resolution through them (execute)). Write permissions usually don't though as you can't change the target of a symlink.

Comment: Unix would disagree with you that "a symlink is not a file". A symlink is a *special* file.

Comment: @hobbs good thing we are a Linux site ;-) (the difference is shown in the 2 links: bsd versus linux on the chmod man page)

Answer (score 9):

You can't. The underlying `chmod` system call simply doesn't support this in Linux, and for that matter, Linux doesn't care about the link's permissions either. From [`man chmod`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/chmod.1):

```
chmod never changes the permissions of symbolic links; the chmod system
call cannot change their permissions.  This is not a problem since  the
permissions  of  symbolic  links  are  never  used.   However, for each
symbolic link listed on the command line, chmod changes the permissions
of  the  pointed-to  file.   In  contrast, chmod ignores symbolic links
encountered during recursive directory traversals.
```

As for hard links or bind mounts, the source's permissions are used, so none of the three standard ways to reflect a file's contents elsewhere can help you in this.

Comment: This answer was also very clear to me, sorry I could only accept one as the answer!